# How to write a for loop to read in excel files into Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop, loaddata

I have 10 excel workbooks (data1.xlsx ~ data10.xlsx), each of which has multiple sheets. I'd like to write a for loop to read in Q4 tabs for each workbook so that I don't have to write repeating codes like what I have below.

```
data1 = pd.read_excel("data1.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Q4')
data2 = pd.read_excel("data2.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Q4')
.
.
.
data9 = pd.read_excel("data9.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Q4')
data10 = pd.read_excel("data10.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Q4')
```

I want the result of each loop to be assigned to a dataframe name (e.g. data1, data2, etc.) I've tried the following, but it only gave me one output and was assigned under `df_name`, not `data1` or `data2`...

```
files = []
filepath = 'C:/Projects/data'
for i in range(1,11):
    df_name = 'data' + str(i)
    df_name = pd.read_excel(filepath+str(i)+'.xlsx', 'Q4')
```

Comment: Creating variable names at run time has a big impact on performance, why would you want to do that and not put everything in the same dataframe and assign a column that identifies if it's data1, data2, etc?

Comment: don't use names `data1`,`data2`,etc but list `all_data = [....]` and `append()` to this list, or use dictionary with `all_data["data1"]`, `all_data["data2"]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Isra. I didn't know of that impact. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a dictionary to store your DataFrames:

```py
files = {f"data{i}": pd.read_excel(f"{filepath}{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="Q4") for i in range(1,11)}
```

Then you can access `data1` by `files['data1']`, etc.